# How to get this image/text iOS layout from Apple?

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, uiscrollview, uitextview

I encountered this image on Apple's UI Design Do's and Don'ts:

[image]

Of course the UI on the left is the one I am shooting for, my question is ***what is the best way to go about getting this UI on the left?*** My initial thought was to use a static table view, with the top cell being the image and the cell below it but I came up with two problems with that approach:

1. How would I get that little water droplet image to span across both cells?
2. How do I make sure that the text field below the image is always the right length no matter how much text is put in (i.e. resizing the text field and the cell depending on the amount of text)?

My second thought was to use a UIScrollView and put the image at the top, constrain the water droplet in between them and then contain a text field below it, but then:

1. How would I make sure that the text field always the right length no matter the amount of text put in?
2. It is pretty impossible to constrain these items in a UIScrollView, how do I properly constrain this in a UIScrollView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a UITableView, and make your cell in the interface builder that can be called through a reuse identifier. And each cell would have the image along with the relevant information that's required. This would fix your first option since you would be able to place the water droplet image over your image and your text.

For your second issue, making sure the cell is of correct height can be done by giving the UITableView dynamic height.

For example, you wouldn't need to insert a heightForRowAtIndexPath function on this tableview, and you can also define:

```
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100; //Can be any value really, but giving a reasonable estimate is helpful
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Also, your the textView you want to use shouldn't be set with any fixed width's or height in the interface builder.

[TableView Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di6ez.png) . Your imageView would be set up somewhat like the blue section in this picture (but fitting the entire width of the screen instead) and your textView would be like the red one. They would all fit in one cell and would make it much easier to organize than using 2 separate cells for one set of content, and you wouldn't have to get into the hassle of setting up the UIScrollView.

Comment: So with regard to the constraints, would I constrain the water droplet to the top, the coffee cup image to the top, and then the textView to the bottom of the cell allowing to stretch if needed?

Comment: Yeah. If I understood correctly you should constrain all your items to the superView (being the cell). I think you could be able to do:
Coffee Cup Image: top:0 left:0 right:0 height:fixed value or relative to the cell's height
TextView: bottom:0 left:0 right:0 height:fixed value or relative to cell height, or just a top instead of the height relative to the coffee cup image
I think with the droplet you'd need to align centrally horizontally and vertically in the cell and adjust the vertical constant to be what you want, and provide a width and height.
Hope this helps